fix the include invalid directive name error on next.js when using threejs-glsl
Three.js is reusing the #include macro to import glsl code into a separate glsl file.
For my use case, I plan to reuse glsl code by using the same macro.
uniform float uTime;
varying vec2 vUv;

#include perlinNoise3d.glsl
void main(){
    ...
}

However, the following error is showing up:
'include' : invalid directive name
In a vite project, that issue is handle by the vite-plugin-glsl plugin.
I wonder how can I make this error go away in next.js

Short answer: next.js doesn't seem to support that construct.
I think the #include construct is special to three.js for shaders.  Standard GLSL (or the ES variant that backs WebGL) doesn't have an include directive (although there are other # directive: line, define, etc.), but not include.  A brief look made me conclude that next.js doesn't support this either, but please verify yourself.
